Access - Need to have two line in form for a table that has a line break in a field
I have a table with two columns. In the Field in the first column I have the input of A and B using a line break (A over B) In the next table column I have number 101. How can I create a continuous form from the table where there are two lines as shown below:
A 101
B 101
Thanks for your help.
I have not tried anything yet. Thinking maybe a query.

If that is a text field with a string value, and you want this split out into 2 complete records, and you want to allow edit of original table, Access does not have functionality to accomplish that, at least not easily. Normalize data structure.

Thanks for the quick reply. I added commas between the areas in one column field and deleted the other columns. I'm not sure how to split it into separate rows on the form. When the rows are separated on the form they have a bound text box where the user can input data. I appreciate your help and can send a file to help explain it better.

As I said this would not be simple and likely require VBA. Would be better to normalize data structure. That means a dependent table where A and B are already in separate records. All infomation to analyze issue should be included in question, not download files. Have you read FAQ's https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking? Could post to a forum that allows attaching files.

Will there always be only two elements in this field or could this be unlimited? When you say "separate rows", do you mean two records or just two lines in one field? What purpose does this serve on a form?

Create a helper function:
Public Function TwoLineAppend( _
    ByVal Text1 As String, _
    ByVal Text2 As String) _
    As String
    
    Const Delimiter As String = vbCrLf
    
    Dim Parts       As Variant
    Dim Text        As String
    
    Parts = Split(Text1, Delimiter)
    Text = _
        Parts(LBound(Parts)) & Space(1) & Text2 & Delimiter & _
        Parts(UBound(Parts)) & Space(1) & Text2

    TwoLineAppend = Text
    
End Function

Use it in your query:
SELECT 
    Field1, 
    Field2, 
    TwoLineAppend([Field1], [Field2]) AS Field12
FROM 
    YourTable;

Output:

